# Player skin on Armor Stand

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am trying to make a wardrobe like setup and I would like to have an armor stand display the outer layer of a player's skin.

**How would I display the outer layer of a player's skin on an armor stand?**

I know how to do both layers at the same time but only one layer eludes me...

Comment: You might need to explain a bit better. What I read was "I know how to do both, but only one". Can you clarify which one you *can* do? And add the command syntax you're using, you might just be using an incorrect keyword.

Comment: @Ben Should be fixed. Do you have any ideas or answers?

Comment: The head (as the block) is the closest thing to putting a skin onto an armor stand, unless you re-skin armors... But that would only limit you to 4 skins..

Comment: You can put entire player skins on the armor stand via `nbt tags`. What I was wondering was how to only do one of the skin's layers...

Comment: Not overly. Tbh I was not aware that player skins had multiple "layers". It was just the skin.

Comment: Starting with 1.8 the entire body (includes arms and legs) could have an "overlay" or second layer. Previously it was just the head.  In my case I have a skin that has a cloak looking thing that I would like to have on a stand to make it look like a closet.

Comment: @Elliot Labs Can you clarify how you are currently putting the entire player skin on armor stands? Pretty sure this isn't possible via `nbt tags`.

Comment: @colorfusion See below...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about vanilla Armor Stands, it's impossible to put a skin on an armor stand the way you describe without a resource pack. At most you can give it a head.

Comment: I am not talking about replacing the texture but "mounting" a player's skin on the stand. Check this resource out:http://www.planetminecraft.com/blog/18-ultimate-armorstands-guide/

Comment: Oh, crap, I think your right about using the player skin using a texture pack... I have to look into this more...

Comment: @ElliotLabs I'm pretty sure someone, I think it was CrushedPixel created a resource pack turning a certain block into a player model.

Answer (score 0):

There is an invisible head on the armor stand. you can make it visible with resource packs that give the 'head' a colour.

That makes it look better than just having the helmet float above the top of the armor stand.

Comment: No, there is no head. You can put heads on, but it does not come with one

Answer (score -3):

go to this site http://statue.jespertheend.com/ type your username in then let in make the command for you drag you mouse to highlight it then do command C and then go to minecraft do type / then right /give username command_block place it down then do command v in the command block and click always active after it makes you break the block [warning do it in creative mode type /gamemode creative and alow cheat cods]

Comment: You really need to break this up and add in some punctuation.  As it stands, this is really hard to understand.

Comment: I don't believe the site works. i get multiple *"POST https://api.imgur.com/3/image 400 (Bad Request)"* in the browser console after i press the start the stuff button